# entity connection error with EF6 and MySQL connector

Tags: c#, mysql, frameworks, entity

I'm getting the following error over and over, despite all attempts to resolve the issue.

The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid

The main issue seems to connect to the EF over several projects in 1 solution.

Here's what I've already tried:

- copied the connection string to the executing project in de web.config file
- added references to the mysql providers
- changed connection string names to the container name

Still get stuck at the construction of my ObjectContext where I get the error above.

```
public EcomContainer() :
        base(@"name=ConString", "EcomContainer")
    {

         Configure();
    }
```

I'm using the Devart mysql dotnet connector, EF6
My testunit is a regular C# console app which works fine with EF
but a new project with a web app such as a wep api or mvc application not.

If anyone would have some experience with this, I welcome any tips.

Thanks

Comment: Hello. We have answered you in ticket # 102247.